# Switching between keyboard layouts on Arch Linux breaks other key bindings

Tags: linux, keyboard, archlinux, keyboard-layout

I'm an Arch Newbie and have this problem:

I want to have two keyboard layouts(en and bg) and to switch between them with alt+shift command. So i did everything as it is written [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LXDE#Keyboard_layout) and everything works. I have two layouts and I switch between them with alt+shift.

But... when i try to move window to another desktop(e.g. ctrl+alt+shift) it doesn't work, it only changes my keyboard layout. And this is not the desired effect. It should only move my window to another desktop, without changing the layout.

The same thing happens if I use ctrl+shift. Then I can't paste in terminal with ctrl+shift+v. Only switches the keyboard layout...

I'm using this line:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle us,bg
```

I'm using LXDE, if it matters.

Comment: same problem. I use "shifts_toggle"

Comment: If using gnome, go into gnome-tweaks -> Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Switching to another layout, and uncheck alt+shift, or whichever combo you need to work and not switch layout.